# Recreate parts of lm() plots with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I have an assignment where I have to recreate the plots generated by the `lm()` function in R using `ggplot2`. Everything needs to be done without using the built in package. I've managed somewhat and I'm on the right track but there are two things which I don't understand.

a) The datapoints in the plots seems "compressed" as in they are shifted towards the center. How are these datapoints calculated? Is there a way to directly manipulate the datapoints with ggplot?

b) If you run the following:

```r
test_object <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
plot(test_object)
```

And look at plot 1 and plot 3, it showcases 99, 119, 118. How can this be done? It seems like it's the three most extreme values.

Comment: If you run `str(test_object)` you will be able to see all the data that is produced from the `lm()` function. Use that data to create plots using `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Axeman I deleted my comment now. OP revised the code to fix the issue.

Comment: I updated the `data = iris`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @OLGJ, you can find more information about each of these plots by reading `?plot.lm`. That page also links functions that you can use to calculate these yourself.

Comment: @Harrison, whoops, sorry missed the edit there!

Comment: I managed to solve this by adding a `geom_label`.